# How to work with input dates in a MySql / Laravel (5.6) / AngularJs application?

Tags: mysql, angularjs, laravel, date

In my application, a user can specify a date in a form, via a datepicker. Doing so, the date has this format : "2018-05-16T12:45:30Z".

Then, I want to store it in a MySql database, in a TIMESTAMP column. 
Later, the user can edit his data. Consequently, the datepicker has to be initialized with the date coming from the server, previously saved.

To manage this, I created an accessor and a mutator :

```
public function setDateNameInputAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['date_name_input'] =  Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', $value);
}

public function getDateNameInputAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
}
```

This code works fine : my front-end reads UTC (Zulu) dates and I can insert timestamps in my database.

However, it's not perfect.

1. Let's say I need for whatever reason to add one hour to a stored date

   ```
    $myObject = MyClass::find(1);
    $theDate = $myObject->dateNameInput;
   ```

Now $theDate is a "T Z format" string, because of the accessor. I could recreate a Carbon object to do my addition, but I think this Carbon -> string -> Carbon transition would be ugly. How can I make a nice operation ?

2. If my applications contains a lot of input dates, with many different model names, is there a way to generalize my accessor and my mutator ?

Actually, is my first approach good ?

Thanks for reading !

Comment: Have you read the documentation for this? There is a special kind of [mutator for dates provided by Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators). I must say time / date / timezones topic (if you want to support whole world) is hard and you should do a little research on how to do it properly - see how SO does it.

Comment: Yes I read it :) If I set $dates with my column name and $dateFormat with :

 'Y-m-d H:i:s' : I get "InvalidArgumentException: Unexpected data found. Trailing data "

or 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z' : I get "SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: 2018-05-16T12:45:30Z"
when inserting.

Comment: I see. What I would do is to not fiddle with how Laravel handles it and just use UTC and in the client code I would play with Moment.js to handle displaying the date correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'll focus more on front-end.

Comment: Note that I dont know all the requirements. Do a research as well, there are some good resources out there. Good luck!